# Query method in drupal

Tags: drupal-6, view

I have node override and a query generated by a view. I need to get results of that query in my node tpl file. What is the method can I use for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [views_embed_view](http://thedrupalblog.com/embedding-view-drupal-6-using-views-embed-view).